# Secondary Drop Down with Preloaded options

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, cakephp

I have Sub-Categories that are related to a Main Category. My sub cat table has the main category id as a foreign key.  I'd like to preload all subcategories using javascript and avoid an extra php file or db query if possible.

Both dropdowns are listing all the records but...
I'd like my second dropdown list of sub-categories to change dynamically onChange (select) of the first dropdown based on the first dropdown's value which is the main cat id.

Example,

```
$data = $this->Category->MainCategory->findall();
$this->set('data',$data);

$data2 = $this->Category->SubCategory->findall();
$this->set('data2',$data2);
```

My arrays look like this:

```
var_dump ($data) = 
array(5) { 
[0]=> array(1) { ["MainCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(10) "Accounting" ["doctype"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["MainCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(15) "Human Resources" ["doctype"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["MainCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(5) "Clubs" ["doctype"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["MainCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["name"]=> string(16) "Service" ["doctype"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["MainCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(9) "Safety" ["doctype"]=> string(1) "2" } } }

var_dump($data2) = 
array(20) {
[0]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(17) "Application Forms" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(19) "Benefit Claim Forms" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["name"]=> string(22) "Evaluations" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["name"]=> string(11) "Leave Forms" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[4]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["name"]=> string(13) "Payroll" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[5]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["name"]=> string(17) "Recruitment" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[6]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["name"]=> string(24) "Training" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[7]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "8" ["name"]=> string(10) "Accounting" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "1" } } 
[8]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["name"]=> string(13) "Staff" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } 
[9]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(14) "Codes" ["main_category_id"]=> string(2) "3" } } 
[10]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["name"]=> string(28) "Reports" ["main_category_id"]=> string(2) "3" }
[11]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["name"]=> string(14) "Plan" ["main_category_id"]=> string(2) "4" } } 
[12]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["name"]=> string(21) "Charts" ["main_category_id"]=> string(2) "4" } } 
[13]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["name"]=> string(11) "Travel" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } 
[14]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["name"]=> string(15) "Financials" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } 
[15]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "16" ["name"]=> string(19) "Event Planning" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } 
[16]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "17" ["name"]=> string(14) "Resources" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } 
[17]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "18" ["name"]=> string(11) "Basics" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } 
[18]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "19" ["name"]=> string(9) "News" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } 
[19]=> array(1) { ["SubCategory"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "20" ["name"]=> string(12) “Funding" ["main_category_id"]=> string(1) "4" } } }
```

--html form ….

```
<td>Category: </td>
<td><select id="main_cat">
<option value=""> </option>
<?php foreach($data as $row){
    echo "<option value=".$row['MainCategory']['id'].">" .$row['MainCategory']['name']. "</option>";
} ?>
</select></td>
<td>Sub Category: </td>
<td><select id="sub_cat">
<option value=""> </option>
<?php foreach($data2 as $row){
    echo "<option value=".$row[‘SubCategory']['id'].">" .$row['SubCategory']['name']. "</option>";
} ?>
</select></td>
```

…..

Comment: dynamically changing the second dropdown will require javascript on the client side. When a change event is fired from the first dropdown, a script will change the options in the second dropdown. Not sure how much of that you have already from what you posted here.

Comment: Also have a look at the Form helper, it's the preferred way of outputting form-inputs in CakePhp and will save you a lot of coding (and mistakes); http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Comment: also - please always specify the cake version you are using! not doing so prevents people from giving correct answers.

Comment: cake 1.1. I do not have any javascript yet. Don't know where to start really.

Comment: I am going to change my sub cat query ($data2) to group by main_category_id and then I am going to try to put that array into js array. can anyone show samples of putting php array into js array or string?

Answer (score 1):

Create a two dimensional javascript array loaded with the sub-categories by category id, then reload the second drop down when the first changes.  Highly simplified [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kgpvS/1/).

For the php, you'll only need to worry about generating the `subCats` array.  Something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var subCats = [
    <?php foreach($data2 as $row){
        echo "[";
        foreach($row as $subcat) {
            echo "\"" . $subcat . "\",";
        }
        echo "]";
    } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: can I grab the value as well from SubCategory.id  'code'subCatHtml += "<option>" + subCats[catId][i] + "</option>";'/code'

Answer (score 0):

just.another.programmer got me on the right track and with some other examples from Jonathan Kuhn, this is the result http://jsfiddle.net/wprLD/9/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var subCats = 
<?php 
$js = array();
foreach($data2 as $sub){

    //get the parent id (main_category_id)
    $parent = $sub['SubCategory']['main_category_id'];
    //if the parent doesn't exist, add it
    if(!isset($js[$parent])){
        //add array with name and id
        $js[$parent] = array(array('id'=>$sub['SubCategory']['id'],'name'=>$sub['SubCategory']['name']));
    //parent does exist
    } else {
        //append this entry name and id
        $js[$parent][] = array('id'=>$sub['SubCategory']['id'],'name'=>$sub['SubCategory']['name']);
    }
}
$js = array_values($js);
echo json_encode($js);
?>
;

function makeSubCatHtml(catId) {
    var subCatHtml = "",
        i;
    //check if the subcats object has this cat Id.
    if(subCats.hasOwnProperty(catId)){
        for (i in subCats[catId]) {
            subCatHtml += "<option value='"+subCats[catId][i].id+"'>" + subCats[catId][i].name + "</option>";
        }
    }

    return subCatHtml;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainCategory").bind("change", function () {
        $("#SubCategory").html(
        makeSubCatHtml(this.selectedIndex));
    });
});
</script>
```